# How to db_dump with correct encoding

Tags: postgresql

I am doing a script that is able to download a db_dump of a remote postgres database.

The problem is that I am trying to get the remote database on the correct enconding and I'm not being able to do it.

the remote database has a LATIN1 enconding and when I execute the script I dumped it is UTF-8

note that I want it to keep the encoding of the remote database so if the remote db is UTF-8 i want the local one to be utf-8 too

does someone know how to accomplish this??

Comment: So you have two databases and a script that copy data from one to another? Remote database has LATIN1 encoding. What's local one? You can choose encoding on CREATE DATABASE only. If you don't create database in your session then it's pre-ordered. SET client_encoding only affects data during transfer.

Answer (score 1):

In PostgreSQL database has an encoding but also a connection to database/session has one.
Server will do the necessary data conversion on-the-fly.

Command pg_dump already uses correct encoding - by default it's original database one, but you can choose different by -E option. If you use -C then it will add CREATE statement with proper encoding (plain text format).

Look at this few lines of pg_dump (-E LATIN1 -C) SQL file:

```
SET client_encoding = 'LATIN1';
...
CREATE DATABASE postgres WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'pl_PL.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'pl_PL.UTF-8';
```

All you have to do is to create database with encoding you want, or use -C pg_dump option to include CREATE command in dump file. PostgreSQL psql (or pg_restore) will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of pg_restore:

```
-C, --create             Zieldatenbank erzeugen
```

This will autocreate the target database from your dump. However, I don't know if the encoding is always correct, or just the default database encoding defined for the server you restore into.

Comment: -C is nott a valid option for me... it generates templates that I dont have and such things... 
Also the above solution doesn't work I don't have a clue why I have the SET to the correct encoding but that doesn't work as it should :(

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and could not find a clean solution. Google led me here. I wound up manually editing the file resulting from pg_dump to add the encoding to its CREATE statement.

Like this:

```
sed -i "s/CREATE DATABASE dbname WITH TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = dbuser/CREATE DATABASE dbname WITH TEMPLATE = template0 OWNER = dbuser ENCODING = desired encoding/" data.sql
```